# Eclipse > why most error icons disappeared in my package explorer

Tags: eclipse

[image]

I am using Eclipse to develop Java project, we can see from the picture, only the parent package src/main displays the ERROR icon, but its sub packages do not display error icons any more even though there are actually errors in all the packages

Comment: Quick check, have you tried restarting eclipse and doing a clean/build? If that workaround works and you have a reproducible test case, please file a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT).

Comment: What is the error that you expect to be seeing on all of the packages?